# HDD cloned to SSD, Ubuntu stucks on Emergency Mode

Tags: ubuntu

I succesfully cloned my HDD to an SSD with a tool for Windows (MiniTool Partition Wizard).

Windows starts correctly but if I select linux bootloader Ubuntu stucks in Emergency Mode. All the data are ok but I can't use GUI.

Is it possible that the problem is the UUID in `/etc/fstab`?

What do I have to do after fstab update? Run `sudo update-grub`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the problem.

In /etc/fstab I had an invalid UUID for /boot/efi mount point, maybe due to the tool I used for cloning the HDD (MiniTool Partition Wizard). The others mount point entries were correct.

We have to use **blkid for the correct UUID to insert in /etc/fstab**. If we use the **Partition unique GUID** from gdisk the system won't start.

On internet I always found that this is the same value but it isn't correct.

**Partition unique GUID** of gdisk is the same as **PARTUUID** from blkid, **not UUID**.

We can also use `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`